# Does a Computer Symbol on the Computer Dice count towards successes?

Tags: paranoia-2017

The Players Handbook says:

> When your character needs to do a non-easy thing in the game or the GM asks you
>   to do a thing, you’ll roll a number of dice equal to your NODE plus the Computer
>   Dice. You always roll the Computer Dice. Even if your NODE is zero or less, you
>   still roll the Computer Dice.
>
> Each rolled dice that shows a 5 or 6 is a ‘success’ and adds one point
>   to your final total. (p 24)

On the Computer Dice, the 6 is replaced with a computer symbol and has a special meaning for the DM. But for the player, does rolling it count as a success?

I do understand that I can rule either way as GM, and that I can choose to be inconsistent about it and punish the traitors who question it. I'm just curious if there is a clear answer or clarification somewhere that I am missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Yes

According to the *Gamemaster's Despotic Power Book* included in the *Acute Paranoia* box:

> **Is the Computer Symbol on the Computer Dice a success or a failure?**
>
> It counts as a success. If you rolled 5 dice and got 2, 2, 4, 5, and the Computer Symbol, then you have 2 successes. Facing Friend Computer's sudden and searing attention is bad enough; give the poor sod a success. (p 170)